# If $\{x_n / n\} \uparrow \infty$, then there exists $\{c_n\}$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_nc_n = \infty$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n c_n < \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to prove the following statement (which may or may not be true):

> Let $\{x_n\}$ denote a positive sequence of real numbers and suppose the sequence $\left\{\frac{x_n}{n}\right\}$ increases monotonically to infinity. 
>   Then there exists a non-negative sequence $\{c_n\}$ such that
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_nc_n = \infty \quad \text{ and } \quad \sum_{n=1}^\infty n c_n < \infty$$

Is the above statement true, or do I need more information about the rate of increase of $\left\{\frac{x_n}{n}\right\}$?

Thank you!

Comment: In the statement you've written, $\{c_n\}$ depends on $\{x_n\}$, not the other way around. Based on your supposed cx, perhaps you wanted to say, there exists $\{c_n\}$ such that for all $\{x_n\}$ this property holds?

Comment: I agree with @jgon. If $\{x_n\}$ can be chosen based off $\{c_n\}$, then one can choose arbitrarily finer functions to satisfy either side of the $p$-series test, or series which sum the sequences $(n \log(n))^{-1}$, $(n \log(n) \log \log (n))^{-1}$, $\cdots$

Comment: @jgon You're right, the counter-example was incoherent. I removed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tidying up the problem by calling $\frac{x_n}{n}=b_n, nc_n=a_n$, we have: if $b_n$ increases monotonically to infinity, find $a_n \ge 0, \Sigma{a_nb_n}=\infty, \Sigma{a_n} <\infty$ and that is very easy without any extra regularity conditions required on $a_n$ (like decreasing or such).

Wlog we can take $b_1 \ge 1$ and then we find an increasing sequence of integers $0=k_0 < k_1 <.... $ such that in $[2^{k_r}, 2^{k_{r+1}})$ there are $n_r \ge 1$ of the $b_n$'s.

(just take $k_1, 2^{k_1}> b_1$ and then $k_2>k_1$, s.t. $2^{k_2}>b_r \ge 2^{k_1}$ for some $r$ etc, so in other words we follow the $b$'s until they break $2^{k_r}$ and then take the next power of two bigger than the corresponding $b$ which can be high if the $b$'s spread out like factorials for example)

Then choosing $a_r=\frac{1}{n_r2^{k_r}}$ for the $b$'s in the $[2^{k_r}, 2^{k_{r+1}})$ interval, obviously the sum of the $ab$'s there is at least $1$ (and there infinitely many such, so the required divergence), while the sum of the $a$'s there is $\frac{1}{2^{k_r}}$ (so dominated by the geometric series of a half, hence convergence) and we are done.

Comment: Hi! I like this answer, but got a little confused with the $r$ subscripts in your notation. What about this:
 
Define $k_n = \lfloor\log_2 b_n\rfloor$. For any index $n$, let $m_{n}$ denote the number of indicies $n_0$ that satisfy $k_{n_0} = k_{n}$.
Now define 
$$
a_n = \frac{1}{m_n 2^{k_n}}
$$

Comment: Looks good sure